# How to implement `protectedFields` in Parse-Server?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I believe this is a new feature in Parse-Server.

By default, the `User` class's `email` field is considered a protected field, meaning that `email` is set to `read: false, write: false` to the public by default. But, every other field in the `User` class is set to `read: true, write: false`

**In Github, I saw this example:**

```
export type ClassLevelPermissions = {
find?: { [string]: boolean },
count?: { [string]: boolean },
get?: { [string]: boolean },
create?: { [string]: boolean },
update?: { [string]: boolean },
delete?: { [string]: boolean },
addField?: { [string]: boolean },
readUserFields?: string[],
writeUserFields?: string[],

// new feature
protectedFields?: { [string]: boolean }
};
```

> For example, with the _User class, if the server was initialized with userSensitiveFields: ['email', 'sin', 'phone'], this would be the equivalent of:

```
{
// CLP for the class ... other 
protectedFields: { "*": ["email", "sin"] }
};
```

> Now if you wanted an moderator role to be able to see the user's email but not the sin and an admin which can read it all

```
{
 protectedFields: { 
   "*": ["email", "sin"],
   "role:moderator": ["sin"],
   "role:admin": []
 }
};
```

After seeing this example, I was still confused where exactly to implement `protectedFields`. Do I implement it in my app's `index.js`, or `main.js`, etc?  Can somebody give me an example of how I can set a field: `phoneNum` to have a `protectedField` similiar to `email`'s default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an option in parse server initialization. See the protectedField option here:
http://parseplatform.org/parse-server/api/master/ParseServerOptions.html

I don't know exactly where/how you are running your Parse server, but it should be something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var app = express();

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: '/home/myApp/cloud/main.js',
  appId: 'myAppId',
  masterKey: 'myMasterKey',
  fileKey: 'optionalFileKey',
  serverURL: 'http://localhost:1337/parse'
  protectedFields: {
    _User: {
      "*": ["email", "sin"],
      "role:moderator": ["sin"],
      "role:admin": []
    }
  }
});

app.use('/parse', api);

app.listen(1337, function() {
  console.log('parse-server-example running on port 1337.');
});
```

Comment: Macedo After implementing `protectedFields: { "*": ["email", "phone"] }`, the phone field is still readable by other users. Did i miss something?

Comment: try ```{ _User: { '*': ['email', 'phone'] } }```. I will update the answer.

Comment: Great! I have one more question. Can I use `protectedFields` to revoke write access from a User Changing his own fields?

Comment: I'd try to do this in a beforeSave trigger.